# Reading Textbox & 'Grabbing' Line into String Variable vb

Tags: vb.net

Okay, I have a textbox, which contains an IP Address, the texbox is populated by a remote file which IS NOT stored - it's downloaded into memory and then placed in the texbox, so it has no actual file in the systems directories, leaving me unable to use the FileStream method.

So, I want to take the text from textbox1, and look for the word 'IP', once this is found I want it to 'grab' that particular line and place it into another textbox (texbox2). How can I do this?

-Please note, there will only ever be ONE line with the word 'IP' in it, and it will always be the first word on the line.

Comment: It would help if you knew what language you were working with... vb.net != vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way...

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Lines.Where(Function(x) x.ToUpper.StartsWith("IP")).FirstOrDefault
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `indexof` to find where the IP text starts

```
Dim sresult = TextBox1.Text.IndexOf("IP")
Dim linebreak = TextBox1.Text.IndexOf(vbCrLf, sresult)
TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text.Substring(sresult, linebreak - sresult)
```